# MySql Union Immediate Merge to Parent table ID

Tags: mysql, database, select, union, union-all

Thanks in advance.

Am trying to merge two table into one. The below query returns the result that i want. Am aware UNION ALL will combine more than one tables.

But i want to merge two table rows immediately after its parent row.

```
SELECT 
  temp.transactionId, 
  temp.amount, 
  temp.transactionType 
FROM 
  (
   (SELECT 
      sale.transaction_id AS transactionId, 
      sale.amount AS amount, 
      'SALE' AS transactionType 
    FROM 
     t_sales sale
    WHERE 
      sale.merchant_id = '1' 
   )

   UNION ALL

   (SELECT 
      refund.refund_transaction_id AS transactionId, 
      refund.amount AS amount, 
      'REFUND' AS transactionType 
   FROM 
      t_refunds refund  
   WHERE 
      refund.merchant_id = '1' 
   )
) 
AS temp
```

The above query returns all `refunds rows` after end of the `sales rows`. But i need to display all the `refund rows immediate after each sales rows`. refunds table has sales tables `ID (Primary Key)`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by `order by` on id/sale_id.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  temp.transactionId, 
  temp.amount, 
  temp.transactionType 
FROM 
  (
   (SELECT 
      sale.transaction_id AS transactionId, 
      sale.amount AS amount, 
      'SALE' AS transactionType,
      id,
      1
    FROM 
     t_sales sale
    WHERE 
      sale.merchant_id = '1' 
   )

   UNION ALL

   (SELECT 
      refund.refund_transaction_id AS transactionId, 
      refund.amount AS amount, 
      'REFUND' AS transactionType,
      sale_id as id,
      2
   FROM 
      t_refunds refund  
   WHERE 
      refund.merchant_id = '1' 
   )
   ORDER BY 4,5
) 
AS temp
```